# Split one column data frame into a data frame with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm working on the text file like this:

```
RES  MON    VOLUMEm3    FLOW_INcms  FLOW_OUTcms
1    1      0.8099E+05  0.1115E-01  0.0000E+00
2    1      0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
3    1      0.2435E+05  0.0000E+00  0.0000E+00
```

So, when I'm opening it as a data frame, in the output I got a dataframe with only one column

```
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(out, 'EDMA_1_rcp26_2025_1_output.rsv'), skiprows = 8, header = 0)
```

How can I split this data frame into multiple columns with columns names from the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the values are separated by spaces, you can specify the optional `delimiter` parameter with regex:

```
pd.read_csv('test.txt', delimiter=r'\s+')
```

Using it on your dataset, I get:

```
   RES  MON  VOLUMEm3  FLOW_INcms  FLOW_OUTcms
0    1    1   80990.0     0.01115          0.0
1    2    1       0.0     0.00000          0.0
2    3    1   24350.0     0.00000          0.0
```

Comment: This method definitely works, but for some reason in my output table header moved to the right, so now column names doesn't match with values in it.

Comment: What's the header of the first column? Blank? If so, does your file begin with some kind of whitespace? Also, are *all* of the rows populated?

Comment: Yes, header of the first column is blank. How can I modify your code to adjust for the blank column header?

Comment: @SergeyGulbin You can set `skiprows=1` to skip the header row, if that's the only one with a missing column. If not, you'll have to post an example.